# How to select suppliers that sold piece P1 to all projects from London?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables:

```
Suppliers S (S#, name-S, Status, City)
PIECES P (P#, name-P, colour, weight, City)
PROJECTS J (J#, name-J, Ciudad)
SELLS SPJ (S#, P#, J#, quantity)
```

I want to find all suppliers that have sold piece `"p1"` to all the projects from London

```
select PROJECTS.j
from SELLS, Suppliers, PIECES, PROJECTS 
where SELLS.s = Suppliers.s
           and  SELLS .p=PIECES .p
           and  SELLS .j=PROJECTS .j
           and PIECES .p="p1"
           and PROYECTOS.ciudad="London"
```

This select suppliers that sell to one project but not for all projects

Data from sells:

```
   supply piece project quantity   
1. s1     p1    j1       5  
2. s1     p1    j3       4  
3. s2     p1    j2       5  
4. s4     p1    j1       1
```

j1 andj2 are projects in London, S4 not sell all propjects but appers in result

Comment: Please use JOIN syntax and not `from SELLS, Suppliers, PIECES, PROJECTS `

Comment: I don't understand your answer

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names of the columns do not allow even to alias the tables because it would be more confusing.
Anyway, join the 4 tables (properly), set the conditions in the WHERE clause, group by supplier and the final condition is in the HAVING clause:

```
select 
  suppliers.s, suppliers.name
from suppliers
inner join sells on sells.s = suppliers.s
inner join pieces on pieces.p = sells.p
inner join projects on projects.j = sells.j
where pieces.p = 'p1' and projects.cioudad = 'London'
group by suppliers.s, suppliers.name
having count(distinct projects.j) = (select count(*) from projects where cioudad = 'London')
```